# I am not able to show an ExtJS Message.Box unless I use Ext.onReady

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have an ExtJS MessageBox that I want to be shown even before the whole page is loaded, but unless I write it within Ext.onReady it doesn't load. How am I supposed to make it work.

This is my Code(which I would like to use):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sorry</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">

                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    msg: 'Activating your account, please wait....',
                    progressText: 'Authenticating E-Mail address',
                    width: 300,
                    wait: true,
                    waitConfig: {interval: 200}
                });         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
<%
    String UUID = request.getParameter("uuid");
    userOperation UA = new userOperation();
    UA.activateUser(UUID);

%>    

<script type="text/javascript">
               Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Welcome', 'Your account has been activated, You can now login');
        </script>
```

Now this is what works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sorry</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.onReady(function() {
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    msg: 'Activating your account, please wait....',
                    progressText: 'Authenticating E-Mail address',
                    width: 300,
                    wait: true,
                    waitConfig: {interval: 200}
                });

         )};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
<%
    String UUID = request.getParameter("uuid");
    userOperation UA = new userOperation();
    UA.activateUser(UUID);

%>    

<script type="text/javascript">
               Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Welcome', 'Your account has been activated, You can now login');
        </script>
```

But the above code sends the MessageBox in the Infinite loop so it defeats the purpose of the box, I need the box to appear only till the Java code in my page is executed. So if MessageBox renders after the page load then there is no purpose to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use parts of the framework before the browser finished loading these. In your case your browser seems to  start executing the last script block before all parts of the framework finished loading.

But there is a convenient way to handle this; You should simply add some markup for your message to the dom and remove it with the onReady event.

Comment: But onReady is called after complete page is loaded, I want that individual MessageBox to be displayed as soon as the Browser reaches the end "})" of MessageBox code till "Java" part finishes its execution which is fair enough. There is way to do it but unfortunately I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: it is basically the same because ExtJS will need to write into the document, so it need to be ready.... The best I can recommend is to create the markup from the start.